# Google's PHP API for login returns no user info

Tags: php, authentication, google-api, google-api-client, google-signin

I'm truly baffled on this one. I have a site with login and everything already implemented, but now I want to add a google login. So I've been doing it using the Google PHP API and a user can login and everything, but whenever I try to call:

```
$payload = $this->client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
```

No errors are thrown, but an empty array is returned.
Everything works fine, the code Google returns validates, the token is validated after that, and it's all fine and good, but this is empty.

The scope is:

```
$this->client->setScopes('email');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the scope to this:

```
$this->client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
```

This works for my current project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was originally just using Google Accounts but then I switched to using Google Plus. I guess they store the values differently